# Ember Checkbox -- Accessing model property from different controller

Tags: ember.js, checkbox

I have a checkbox on a modal popup and need it to be checked based on the value on an unrelated model. The model is Team and the property I need to access is called syncAccount (boolean), so the input helper would likely look something like this:

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="syncAccount" checked=team.syncAccount }}
```

How can I access or bind to team.syncAccount from the modal? I have a ModalImportController, but no associated route. Is there some way in this controller I can assign a property that looks up or binds to the value of syncAccount for the current team (and is updated as they toggle it)?

Similarly, I need toggling the checkbox to send an update request for this field. Will this need to be an ajax request, or is there some way to set the model used by the checkbox to point to a team so that I can call @model.save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to a property from another controller you first need to include that via `needs` like so:

```
App.ModalImportController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: "team",
  teamController: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.team"),
});
```

then you would have access to it's properties like so:

```
// still in ModalImportController
syncAccount: function() {
    return this.get('teamController.syncAccount');
}.property('teamController.syncAccount')
```

I haven't tested it now, but that's the way I did it in a slightly different setup.

source:
[http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/][1]

For toggeling to send an update request I use:

```
syncAccount: Ember.computed('model.syncAccount', {
    get: function() {
        return this.get('model.syncAccount');
    },
    set: function(key, value) {
        this.set('model.syncAccount', value);
        // do all you need to do via AJAX here
        return value;
    }
})
```

note, that you also GET the value from here, so change your input-helper to:

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="syncAccount" value=syncAccount }}
```

Comment: I don't have a team controller. Instead, in the application controller, I have a helper called currentTeam. I'm using your suggestion to access the value like this: `syncAccount: function() { this.get('applicationController.currentTeam.syncAccount'); }.property('currentTeam.syncAccount')` The value of syncAccount doesn't seem to get looked up initially. From the dev tools, if I call $E.syncAccount, it returns this: function() App.ModalsController.Ember.ObjectController.extend.syncAccount() After toggling the checkbox, calling $E.syncAccount returns `true`. How can I set this value before open?

Comment: Looks as though it was a problem with the input helper:
value=syncAccount wasn't working, but value="syncAccount" marks the checkbox as checked on first open. Toggling still doesn't work (i.e. clicking the checkbox doesn't toggle between check/no check. Do you happen to know if this is behavior that I have to handle in the controller (i.e. not a default?)